# CSS Typewriter Effect

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to create a type writer effect where the text is written out and then at the end of the sentence the | cursor blinks for 2 seconds before starting the next sentence (second h1) and then writes that sentence.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  padding-top: 5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.typewriter h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(30, end), blink-caret .5s;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
  <h1>First Sentence Here</h1>
  <h1>Second Sentence Here</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `animation-delay` using CSS variables. For each `h1` element (accept the 1st - it uses the default), set the `--delay` variable. This will add the relevant delay to each animation.

You should also change the `animation-fill-mode` to `both`, so the items would retain their start and end states.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  padding-top: 5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.typewriter h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(30, end) both, blink-caret .5s both;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--delay, 0) * 1s), calc(var(--delay, 0) * 1s + 3.5s);
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
  <h1>First Sentence Here</h1>

  <h1 style="--delay: 4">Second Sentence Here</h1>
</div>
```